# What is the problem in my non-linear analysis apdl code?

Tags: ansys, non-linear

everyone
I'm using Ansys apdl to perform a non-linear analysis.
I'm looking for cracks region on a T cross-section concrete beam.
The non-linear analysis closes the ansys and does not converge to a solution.
May someone help me, please?
What am I doing wrong?
I'll appreciate it if someone could help me.
The code is below. You can see some comments in portuguese.

```
!T beam    
!    
/clear     
!    
/Filename,T beam        !File name do Viga T    
/Tittle, T beam analysis    !Title     
!     
/Units, SI,,,,,,,,,          
!    
/prep7     
!        
!beam length (m)     
L=4 !m     
!     
!Model scale       
Esc=1           !real model      
!        
!Force (N) and force orientation(+, -)      
!number nodes which receive the load at each side     
nodes=21        
fp=-10000/nos       
!       
!reinforcement area - 2 bars, diameter= 8 mm      
A=(5.026548e-5)*2 !m²      
!       
!T beam dimensions      
lt=0.48*Esc
ct=L*Esc    
et=0.05*Esc 
ht=0.40*Esc 
!        
!element type     
et,1,solid65,9.66e-4       
!       
!element 1 Keyopts       
!KEYOPT, ITYPE, KNUM, VALUE      
keyopt,1,1,1
keyopt,1,3,0
!keyopt,1,5,1
keyopt,1,6,3
keyopt,1,7,1
keyopt,1,8,0
!        
!et,1,solid65,0,0.003590,0,,1,3,1,1,,,       
et,2,reinf264         
!         
!Propriedades do Concreto armado         
/pnum, mat, 0          
secnum,1                   
mat,1          
mp,ex,1,28e9
mp,prxy,1,0.2           !Coeficiente de Poisson do concreto - material 1        
mp,dens,1,25e3,,,,,     !Densidade do material (N)         
tb,concr,1          !ativa a tabela de dados para um material considerado            
tbdata,1,0.8,0.2,2.5e6,25e6,,,  !Define as propridades não-lineares para o material 1         
!          
!Propriedades do Aço         
secnum,2         
mat,2         
mp,ex,2,200e9
mp,prxy,2,0.3
mp,dens,2,78.5e3
tb,biso,2        
tbdata,1,2000   
tbdata,2,500e6       
!        
!reinforcement position - reinf265           
mat,2        
secnum,2        
sectype,2,reinf,smear          
secdata, 2, A, , ,0,elef,2,0.7,0.7        
!          
!Ativa o material 1 e a secnum,1         
mat,1        
secnum,1          
!           
!cross section keypoints          
K,1,0*Esc,0*Esc,0.20*Esc       
K,2,0*Esc,0*Esc,0.28*Esc       
K,3,0,0.02*Esc,0.28*Esc        
K,4,0*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0.28*Esc         
K,5,0*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,lt*Esc         
K,6,0*Esc,ht*Esc,lt*Esc         
K,7,0*Esc,ht*Esc,0.28*Esc          
K,8,0*Esc,ht*Esc,0.20*Esc            
K,9,0*Esc,ht*Esc,0*Esc          
K,10,0*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0*Esc          
K,11,0*Esc,0.02*Esc,0.20*Esc          
K,12,0*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0.20*Esc         
!           
K,13,ct*Esc,0*Esc,0.20*Esc        
K,14,ct*Esc,0*Esc,0.28*Esc        
K,15,ct*Esc,0.02*Esc,0.28*Esc       
K,16,ct*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0.28*Esc        
K,17,ct*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,lt*Esc      
K,18,ct*Esc,ht*Esc,lt*Esc       
K,19,ct*Esc,ht*Esc,0.28*Esc      
K,20,ct*Esc,ht*Esc,0.20*Esc       
K,21,ct*Esc,ht*Esc,0.00*Esc        
K,22,ct*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0*Esc         
K,23,ct*Esc,0.02*Esc,0.20*Esc        
K,24,ct*Esc,(ht-et)*Esc,0.20*Esc          
!          
!Areas da alma, recebe o reforço          
a,1,2,3,11         
a,1,2,14,13 !area 2        
a,1,11,23,13    !area 3         
a,13,14,15,23   !area 4         
a,14,15,3,2 !area 5           
a,3,11,23,15    !area 6        
!        
!Define volumes a partir da união de áreas existentes        
va,1,2,3,4,5,6         
!       
!Restante da alma, até a mesa         
a,3,4,12,11     !area 7          
a,11,12,24,23       !area 8          
a,4,16,15,3     !area 9        
a,15,16,24,23       !area 10         
a,4,16,24,12        !area 11        
!          
!Define volumes a partir da união de áreas existentes        
va,6,7,8,9,10,11       
!        
!Define o restante da nervura, no topo da mesa      
a,4,7,8,12  !area 12         
a,12,24,20,8    !area 13         
a,16,19,20,24   !area 14       
a,7,19,16,4 !area 15        
a,19,20,8,7 !area 16         
!       
!Define o volume da nervura, no topo da mesa       
va,11,12,13,14,15,16        
!       
!Deine a mesa       
a,8,9,10,12     !area 17       
a,9,21,22,10    !area 18         
a,24,12,10,22   !area 19         
a,20,21,22,24   !area 20         
a,20,8,9,21 !area 21         
!         
!Define o volume da nervura, no topo da mesa        
va,13,17,18,19,20,21         
!        
!Define o restante da mesa     
a,4,5,6,7   !area 22        
a,17,18,19,16   !area 23         
a,16,17,5,4 !area 24         
a,5,17,18,6 !area 25          
a,6,7,19,18 !area 26       
!        
!Define o volume da nervura, no topo da mesa       
va,15,22,23,24,25,26         
!       
!Tamanho da malha aplicada ao bloco 1       
!ESIZE, SIZE, NDIV       
esize,0.025*Esc         !Elementos de malha com dimensões de 2,5 cm de lado!!        
!         
!Comando de malha       
vmesh,1         
!         
!Propriedades do Aço        
mat,2         
secnum,2          
!             
!Transforma as áreas selecionadas em barras de aço      
ereinf,         
!        
!Define o nível de translucência, a qual permite ver a posição das barras no interior da viga        
/TRLCY, elem,0.5,all         
!         
!Ativa o material 1          
mat,1          
secnum,1          
!             
!Define as propriedades associadas aos volumes         
vatt,1,,,        
!           
!Tamanho da malha aplicada ao bloco 2         
!ESIZE, SIZE, NDIV        
esize,0.025*Esc         !Elementos de malha com dimensões de 2,5 cm de lado!!      
!          
!Comando de malha       
!VMESH, NV1, NV2, NINC       
vmesh,2,5       
!       
!Apresenta os nós do modelo       
/PNUM, node, on      
!        
!Condições de contorno        
!D, Node, Lab, VALUE, VALUE2, NEND, NINC, Lab2, Lab3, Lab4, Lab5, Lab6        
!         
D, 11, ux      
D, 11, uy      
!D, 11, uz      
!      
D, 172, ux      
D, 172, uy      
!D, 172, uz       
!        
D, 174, ux      
D, 174, uy       
!D, 174, uz       
!       
D, 173, ux      
D, 173, uy       
!D, 173, uz        
!       
D, 171, ux        
D, 171, uy       
!D, 171, uz        
!        
D, 170, ux          
D, 170, uy         
!D, 170, uz         
!        
D, 810, ux         
D, 810, uy         
!D, 810, uz          
!        
D, 651, ux          
D, 651, uy        
!D, 651, uz        
!         
D, 492, ux        
D, 492, uy         
!D, 492, uz        
!          
D, 175, ux        
D, 175, uy         
!D, 175, uz         
!        
D, 169, ux         
D, 169, uy          
!D, 169, uz              
!         
D, 809, ux        
D, 809, uy         
!D, 809, uz          
!          
D, 650, ux         
D, 650, uy        
!D, 650, uz          
!        
D, 491, ux          
D, 491, uy        
!D, 491, uz        
!          
D, 176, ux        
D, 176, uy          
!D, 176, uz          
!        
D, 168, ux        
D, 168, uy           
!D, 168, uz            
!            
D, 808, ux          
D, 808, uy          
!D, 808, uz         
!         
D, 649, ux        
D, 649, uy          
!D, 649, uz             
!         
D, 490, ux        
D, 490, uy         
!D, 490, uz         
!         
D, 177, ux       
D, 177, uy        
!D, 177, uz        
!        
D, 167, ux       
D, 167, uy        
!D, 167, uz        
!       
D, 807, ux        
D, 807, uy       
!D, 807, uz       
!       
D, 648, ux       
D, 648, uy       
!D, 648, uz        
!        
D, 489, ux      
D, 489, uy       
!D, 489, uz       
!        
D, 178, ux       
D, 178, uy        
!D, 178, uz        
!        
D, 166, ux        
D, 166, uy        
!D, 166, uz         
!           
D, 806, ux      
D, 806, uy          
!D, 806, uz      
!         
D, 647, ux        
D, 647, uy      
!D, 647, uz      
!       
D, 488, ux        
D, 488, uy       
!D, 488, uz       
!          
D, 179, ux       
D, 179, uy      
!D, 179, uz        
!       
D, 165, ux        
D, 165, uy       
!D, 165, uz      
!         
D, 805, ux        
D, 805, uy         
!D, 805, uz       
!         
D, 646, ux        
D, 646, uy       
!D, 646, uz         
!         
D, 487, ux          
D, 487, uy          
!D, 487, uz          
!            
D, 180, ux         
D, 180, uy         
!D, 180, uz        
!         
D, 164, ux         
D, 164, uy         
!D, 164, uz          
!        
D, 804, ux      
D, 804, uy      
!D, 804, uz      
!       
D, 645, ux       
D, 645, uy      
!D, 645, uz      
!      
D, 486, ux       
D, 486, uy     
!D, 486, uz      
!     
D, 181, ux      
D, 181, uy      
!D, 181, uz      
!     
D, 163, ux      
D, 163, uy     
!D, 163, uz      
!      
D,803, ux      
D, 803, uy      
!D, 803, uz      
!       
D, 644, ux       
D, 644, uy      
!D, 644, uz     
!      
D, 485, ux       
D, 485, uy      
!D, 485, uz      
!        
D, 182, ux     
D, 182, uy      
!D, 182, uz       
!      
!Apoios na outra extremidade    
D, 1, ux        
D, 1, uy      
!D, 1, uz      
!     
D, 2, ux     
D, 2, uy      
!D, 2, uz   
!       
D, 3, ux       
D, 3, uy       
!D, 3, uz       
!          
D, 4, ux        
D, 4, uy       
!D, 4, uz      
!        
D, 5, ux         
D, 5, uy      
!D, 5, uz        
!        
D, 12, ux       
D, 12, uy        
!D, 12, uz     
!      
D, 652, ux      
D, 652, uy      
!D, 652, uz       
!        
D, 493, ux       
D, 493, uy       
!D, 493, uz       
!        
D, 334, ux       
D, 334, uy       
!D, 334, uz        
!      
D, 333, ux      
D, 333, uy     
!D, 333, uz      
!        
D, 13, ux       
D, 13, uy        
!D, 13, uz        
!        
D, 653, ux        
D, 653, uy       
!D, 653, uz        
!        
D, 494, ux       
D, 494, uy      
!D, 494, uz      
!       
D, 335, ux       
D, 335, uy      
!D, 335, uz       
!        
D, 332, ux       
D, 332, uy        
!D, 332, uz        
!          
D, 14, ux       
D, 14, uy         
!D, 14, uz       
!          
D, 654, ux       
D, 654, uy      
!D, 654, uz       
!       
D, 495, ux      
D, 495, uy       
!D, 495, uz     
!      
D, 336, ux      
D, 336, uy      
!D, 336, uz       
!       
D, 331, ux       
D, 331, uy        
!D, 331, uz       
!      
D, 15, ux      
D, 15, uy      
!D, 15, uz      
!      
D, 655, ux       
D, 655, uy      
!D, 655, uz      
!         
D, 496, ux        
D, 496, uy      
!D, 496, uz      
!       
D, 337, ux      
D, 337, uy         
!D, 337, uz      
!      
D, 330, ux       
D, 330, uy         
!D, 330, uz        
!       
D, 16, ux     
D, 16, uy      
!D, 16, uz       
!      
D, 656, ux      
D, 656, uy      
!D, 656, uz       
!       
D, 497, ux     
D, 497, uy       
!D, 497,uz      
!      
D, 338, ux     
D, 338, uy      
!D, 338, uz         
!      
D, 329, ux     
D, 329, uy      
!D, 329, uz      
!      
D, 17, ux     
D, 17, uy     
!D, 17, uz      
!       
D, 657, ux      
D, 657, uy       
!D, 657, uz         
!       
D, 498, ux       
D, 498, uy      
!D, 498, uz      
!       
D, 339, ux       
D, 339, uy         
!D, 339, uz        
!        
D, 328, ux       
D, 328, uy        
!D, 328, uz        
!        
D, 18, ux        
D, 18, uy        
!D, 18, uz        
!         
D, 658, ux      
D, 658, uy      
!D, 658, uz       
!       
D, 499, ux       
D, 499, uy      
!D, 499, uz       
!       
D, 340, ux      
D, 340, uy      
!D, 340, uz       
!      
D, 327, ux      
D, 327, uy      
!D, 327, uz      
!       
D, 19, ux      
D, 19, uy     
!D,  19, uz         
!      
D, 659, ux     
D, 659, uy      
!D, 659, uz     
!     
D, 500, ux     
D, 500, uy     
!D, 500, uz     
!      
D, 341, ux      
D, 341, uy      
!D, 341, uz     
!      
D, 326, ux      
D, 326, uy     
!D, 326, uz     
!    
!Condições de contorno impostas à mesa     
!     
D, 14515, uz     
D, 14676, uz     
D, 14675, uz      
!     
D, 18380, uz     
D, 18381, uz     
D, 18379, uz      
!     
D, 18363, uz     
D, 18364, uz     
D, 18355, uz      
!      
D, 14491, uz       
D, 14500, uz    
D, 14499, uz     
!     
!Retira a numeração dos nós do modelo      
/PNUM, node, off     
!     
!Plota os elementos de malha     
esel,all     
eplot      
!      
!Insere as forças nodais nos nós desejados      
!Ponto x=1.75m     
F,12982,fy,fp     
!     
F,13288,fy,fp      
F,13626,fy,fp     
F,13785,fy,fp     
F,13944,fy,fp      
!       
F,14585,fy,fp      
!      
F,16752,fy,fp      
F,16753,fy,fp     
F,16754,fy,fp     
F,16755,fy,fp      
F,16756,fy,fp      
F,16757,fy,fp      
F,16758,fy,fp      
!      
F,19764,fy,fp     
!     
F,20062,fy,fp     
F,20221,fy,fp     
F,20380,fy,fp      
F,20539,fy,fp       
F,20698,fy,fp      
F,20857,fy,fp      
!       
F,21016,fy,fp      
!      
!Ponto x=2.25m      
F,12962,fy,fp      
!      
F,13308,fy,fp     
F,13606,fy,fp     
F,13765,fy,fp       
F,13924,fy,fp      
!      
F,14605,fy,fp       
!        
F,16612,f y,fp      
F,16613,fy,fp      
F,16614,fy,fp      
F,16615,fy,fp      
F,16616,fy,fp      
F,16617,fy,fp      
F,16618,fy,fp       
!       
F,19744,fy,fp        
!     
F,20082,fy,fp      
F,20241,fy,fp     
F,20400,fy,fp      
F,20559,fy,fp      
F,20718,fy,fp      
F,20877,fy,fp      
F,21036,fy,fp       
!       
!Solução      
/solu      
!      
!ANTYPE, Antype, Status, LDSTEP, SUBSTEP, Action, --, PRELP     
antype,static      
!     
!inclui os efeitos de grandes deflexões      
nlgeom, on     
!      
!Especifica o número de passos passos a serem considerados, incluindo o número de passos mínimos e 
máximos       
!NSUBST, NSBSTP, NSBMX, NSBMN, Carry     
nsubst,50, 1000, 1     
!    
!NROPT, Option1, Option2, Optval      
nropt,auto, crpl, 0.15    
!    
!ARCLEN, Key, MAXARC, MINARC    
arclen,on     
!     
!Resolve para a condição de carregamento selecionada ("load step")     
solve,    
!     
/post1      
set,list     
!     
finish
```

Comment: You should not post files that contain unnecessary or obscure parts (here: comments). Also, it would be reasonable to show a *relevant* part of the log.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mr. Zkoza

Answer (score 0):

@jb_ fp=-10000/nos nos is not defined so there is a divide by zero issue.  From there I'd ask why are you using older, non-supported element types (solid65).  You should use a updated element type and material model combination.
Mike